# IPv6 Support for iOS App and support AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ipv6, appstore-approval, ipv4

I have submit my iPhone app last week, due to IPv6 Support issue,app Rejected with below message,

```
"Apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required."
```

So Now we are ready to configure IPv6.
But In my application we are interacting with AWS server.So as the Apple Forums said that IPv6 will not support AWS interaction.
Now How to Resolve this situation and how to acheive this.

Please suggest.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Although this question mentions AWS and the one above mentions Google, both boil down to "what to do when I can't host the server for my iOS app on IPv6?"

Comment: Just to add another note. If you are using AWS SDK for iOS upgrade your app to use the sdk version 2.4.2 or higher

Comment: @Karthik, I'm running into the same issue as above in terms of getting my apps rejected.  I have updated my app to use AWS SDK version 2.4.8, which I thought resolved the issue, but just today I got another rejection from Apple for the same reason.  Is there some update to my AWS iOS implementation that I need to make to take advantage of IPv6?  I read something about using dualstack S3 endpoints, but the iOS documentation makes no reference to dualstack.  Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple doesn't care about the server side. Apple cares about your app, and they want it to be able to run in the absence of IPv4. They assume that networks will run DNS64+NAT64 to translate back to IPv4 on behalf of services that aren't ready yet, such as AWS.

Apple's guidelines for how to achieve and test app-readiness are [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a). If you follow the NAT64 link and search for "internet sharing", you'll see instructions on how to enable Apple's NAT64 in El Capitan. You can assume that this is the same environment they'll test your app in.

You can also assume it's a similar environment to what some networks already run today, but iOS devices are still running IPv4 alongside IPv6. Apple wants to be able to eradicate IPv4 from the device in the future.